# JOptionPane: Installing Custom icon has no effect when look and feel set

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane, uimanager

I would like to install a custom icon in place of the standard JOptionPane information icon..

I tried

```
ImageIcon myCustomIcon = ...;
UIManager.put("OptionPane.informationIcon", myCustomIcon);
```

However, apparently this has no effect due to the following line:

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
```

Commenting out this line gives the correct behaviour. I have of course tried putting the icon into the UIManager both before/after the look and feel is being set.
Can I somehow combine the two to override the information icon globally?

I am working on Ubuntu 10.04 right now..

Regards,
Morten

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works fine for me using the Metal and Windows LAF's.

Maybe your LAF doesn't support the UIManager property. Check out [UIManager Defaults](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/09/uimanager-defaults/) for a list of properties.

If you need more help the post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the link. It seems that there is an issue with my L&F.. My application is using the GTK+ L&F on ubuntu and using your UIManager Defaults link, the "OptionPane.informationIcon" is defaulted to null (which I think is indicative of it not being used)..

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to specify your icon **after** setting look&feel, in such a way:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,
    "Eggs are not supposed to be green.",
    "Inane custom dialog",
    JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE,
    myCustomIcon);
```

### Update:

The following code works fine on my Windows 7:

```
import java.net.URL;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class OptionPaneIcon {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        ImageIcon myCustomIcon = loadImageIcon("image.png");
        UIManager.put("OptionPane.informationIcon", myCustomIcon);
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hello!");
    }

    /** Returns an ImageIcon, or null if the path was invalid. */
    private static ImageIcon loadImageIcon(String path) {
        URL imgURL = OptionPaneIcon.class.getResource(path);
        if (imgURL != null) {
            return new ImageIcon(imgURL);
        } else {
            System.err.println("Couldn't find file: " + path);
                return null;
        }
    }
}
```

P.S. Sorry for my impatience.

Comment: Yes, I can manually set the icon every time, but I would like to set it once and for all so that all message boxes uses the same icon (since I already have quite a few message boxes being displayed throughout the code without specifying a custom icon).